# How to get the address of a constant in MIPS?

Tags: mips

I am trying to implement a for loop in mips like this:

```
#  {
#     int sum = 0;
#     for(int x = 0; x < n; x++)
#       if ( v[x] > 2 )
#           sum += v[x];
#     return sum;
#  }
```

I have the loop correctly but I can't get the size of the loop right. The loops functions as intended but it runs one extra time. It should be printing a 31 but it ends up running the loop an extra time and getting a 10 from somewhere then getting a 41 as the end result.

Here is my code:

```
            .eqv        SIZE        8  
values:     .half       6, 5, 1, 9, -2, 3, 8, 2
endl:       .asciiz     "\n"
endv:

# -------------------------------------------------#  text/code section
.text
.globl  main 
main:
# ------
    #TODO: call doSum(values, SIZE)
    la  $s0, values #&v[0]
    la  $s7, endv   
    li  $a0, 0      #sum = 0

loop:
    lh  $t1, ($s0)  #v[X]
    li  $t2, 2      #$t2 = 2
    bgt $t1, $t2, sumPlus
    j   increment   #skip over sumPlus if not > 2

sumPlus:
    add $a0, $a0, $t1   #sum += v[x]

increment:
    add $s0, $s0, 2 #x++
    blt $s0, $s7, loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a line feed character and a null terminator (`endl:       .asciiz     "\n"`) before `endv`, so you're including them in the array that you're summing from. I don't know much about MIPS, but because \n has the value 10 (dec) and the \0 has the value 0. I assume that they're bytes and this is being run on a machine that is little-endian, so as a signed halfword they're interpreted as 10 (dec).

I think that just moving the `endv` label to the actual end of the array (just before `endl:`) will solve this.

Comment: That was an easy fix. Thank you!